# Not connecting to socket.io

Tags: websocket, socket.io, client-server

I am building a multiplayer chess game in flutter. The game and server connection were almost done, and everything was working fine when suddenly I am now stuck on not getting connected to socket.io server.
I think some version issues are there, I tried so many things yet no results. Can you please help to resolve the same.

These are the code snippets:

index.js:

```
// importing modules
const express = require("express");
const http = require("http");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
var server = http.createServer(app);
const Room = require("./models/room");
var io = require("socket.io")(server);

// middle ware
app.use(express.json());

const DB =
  "mongodb+srv:*********@cluster0.qkyoux9.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority";

io.on("connection", (socket) => {
  console.log("connected!");
  socket.on("createRoom", async ({ nickname }) => {
    console.log(nickname);
    try {
      // room is created
      let room = new Room();
      let player = {
        socketID: socket.id,
        nickname,
        playerType: "X",
      };
      room.players.push(player);
      room.turn = player;
      room = await room.save();
      console.log(room);
      const roomId = room._id.toString();

      socket.join(roomId);
      // io -> send data to everyone
      // socket -> sending data to yourself
      io.to(roomId).emit("createRoomSuccess", room);
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  });

  socket.on("joinRoom", async ({ nickname, roomId }) => {
    try {
      if (!roomId.match(/^[0-9a-fA-F]{24}$/)) {
        socket.emit("errorOccurred", "Please enter a valid room ID.");
        return;
      }
      let room = await Room.findById(roomId);

      if (room.isJoin) {
        let player = {
          nickname,
          socketID: socket.id,
          playerType: "O",
        };
        socket.join(roomId);
        room.players.push(player);
        room.isJoin = false;
        room = await room.save();
        io.to(roomId).emit("joinRoomSuccess", room);
        io.to(roomId).emit("updatePlayers", room.players);
        io.to(roomId).emit("updateRoom", room);
      } else {
        socket.emit(
          "errorOccurred",
          "The game is in progress, try again later."
        );
      }
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  });

  socket.on("tap", async ({ index, roomId }) => {
    try {
      let room = await Room.findById(roomId);

      let choice = room.turn.playerType; // x or o
      if (room.turnIndex == 0) {
        room.turn = room.players[1];
        room.turnIndex = 1;
      } else {
        room.turn = room.players[0];
        room.turnIndex = 0;
      }
      room = await room.save();
      io.to(roomId).emit("tapped", {
        index,
        choice,
        room,
      });
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  });

  socket.on("winner", async ({ winnerSocketId, roomId }) => {
    try {
      let room = await Room.findById(roomId);
      let player = room.players.find(
        (playerr) => playerr.socketID == winnerSocketId
      );
      player.points += 1;
      room = await room.save();

      if (player.points >= room.maxRounds) {
        io.to(roomId).emit("endGame", player);
      } else {
        io.to(roomId).emit("pointIncrease", player);
      }
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  });
});

mongoose
  .connect(DB)
  .then(() => {
    console.log("Connection successful!");
  })
  .catch((e) => {
    console.log(e);
  });

server.listen(port, "0.0.0.0", () => {
  console.log(`Server started and running on port ${port}`);
});
```

This is the pubsec file:

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  socket_io_client: ^2.0.2
  provider: ^6.0.2
```

This is the packages.json:

```
{
  "name": "server",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node ./index.js",
    "dev": "nodemon ./index.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^2.0.15"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.18.0",
    "http": "^0.0.1-security",
    "mongoose": "^6.3.1",
    "socket.io": "^2.0.2"
  }
}
```

This is the socket_io_client :

```
import 'package:socket_io_client/socket_io_client.dart' as IO;

class SocketClient {
  IO.Socket? socket;
  static SocketClient? _instance;

  SocketClient._internal() {
    socket = IO.io('http://*****:3000', <String, dynamic>{
      'transports': ['websocket'],
      'autoConnect': false,
    });
    socket!.connect();
  }

  static SocketClient get instance {
    _instance ??= SocketClient._internal();
    return _instance!;
  }
}
```

The "Connected" is not happening as mentioned above in the code:

```
io.on("connection", (socket) => {
  console.log("connected!");
```

Comment: Mongo Db connections are working fine:                                                                 
    mongoose
  .connect(DB)
  .then(() => {
    console.log("Connection successful!");
  })
  .catch((e) => {
    console.log(e);
  });

server.listen(port, "0.0.0.0", () => {
  console.log(`Server started and running on port ${port}`);
});